# Окно информации по annotation, Apple MapKit (Swift 3)

Tags: xcode, swift, map

Моя задача поворачивать аннотацию(автомобиль) по направлению.
Проблема заключается в том, что при повороте `annotationView.tranform...` выглядит это так:

[image: 1вар]

Есть второй вариант, при котором общий вид верный, поворот не вьюхи, а самого изображения, но есть другая проблема, при повороте `UIImage` качество изображения сильно портится, и автомобиль выглядит размытым и пиксельным, на примере не сильно видно, тк сжал общую картинку:

[![2вар][2]][2][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Как поворачивать автомобиль, не теряя качество изображения авто и чтобы описание по нажатию оставалось сверху, а не вертелось вместе с ним?

Подробности как я это делаю:

В методе `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?`

для варианта, который описан первым (поворот вью) делаю

```
anView?.transform = self.mapView.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(degreesToRadians(degrees: self.angleDegrees)))
```

для второго варианта, где поворачиваю UIImage делаю

```
anView?.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)?.imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat(self.angleDegrees))
```

используя расширение:

```
extension UIImage {
public func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat) -> UIImage {

    let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
        return $0 / 180.0 * CGFloat(Double.pi)
    }

    let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
    let t = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degreesToRadians(degrees));
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t
    let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
    let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    bitmap!.translateBy(x: rotatedSize.width / 2.0, y: rotatedSize.height / 2.0);

    bitmap!.rotate(by: degreesToRadians(degrees));

    bitmap!.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

    bitmap!.draw(cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: -size.width / 2, y: -size.height / 2, width: size.width, height: size.height))

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

}

Comment: Возможно это связано с тем, что по дефолту scaleToFill. Попробуйте `annotationView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit` или  `annotationView!.contentMode = .center` задать.А так побольше бы информации как Вы все это делаете.

Comment: @VAndrJ я дополнил вопрос добавив подробности по двум вариантам. По `annotationView!.contentMod` - я попробовал оба Ваши варианта в двух своих - не помогло, только при применении .center иконка стала огромной

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем методе поворота изображения измените

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
```

на

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rotatedSize, false, 0.0)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь при повороте изображения картинка не портится, и окно доп инфо остается вверху